# Yum can't get repo update but curl can get url

Tags: yum

In a Oracle Linux docker image, I can get this url with curl :

```
# curl -I https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/xml
ETag: "28f9cc1bb8a41a0e928e2e36ff54b46f:1675908836.186431"
Last-Modified: Thu, 09 Feb 2023 02:12:54 GMT
Server: AkamaiNetStorage
Content-Length: 3697
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2023 15:51:36 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

But, I can't pull update from yum

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: ovl, ulninfo
https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable
```

Any idea to debug the http GET request of yum ?

Thank you for your help